# producing categorical variable depending on how the number starts in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a vector of numbers that start with the digits 01,02,03,04,05,06. Imagine I want to create a categorical variable such as "A" if the number starts with 01 or 02, "B" if the number starts with 03 or 04 and "C"  if it starts wtih 05 and 06. Any ideas?

Comment: If your number starts with a 0, it's not a number it's a string or factor already. You probably want the `substr` function. `substr(your_number_vector, 1, 2)`.

Comment: absolutely right Gregor. It is a string what I have

Comment: Use @Gregor's solution to extract the beginning of the string. Then you could do something like a series of nested `ifelse()` statements combined with the boolean `||` (OR) operators to selectively create the variable.

Comment: Yes, it works. If you guys post the answer I will flag it as answered. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Create sample data frame
set.seed(pi)
sample_len <- 20

x <- paste0("0",
       sample(1:6, sample_len, replace = TRUE),
       sample(1:100, sample_len)
       )

df <- data.frame(N = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C"
categorical <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 1, each = 2)

# Select categorical letter with second digit
df$Letters <- categorical[as.integer(substring(df$N, 2, 2))]

# Convert to factor
df$Letters <- as.factor(df$Letters)

df

#      N       Letters
# 1   0223       A
# 2    052       C
# 3   0313       B
# 4   0210       A
# 5  04100       B
# 6   0476       B
# 7   0157       A
# 8   0285       A
# 9   0452       B
# 10  0469       B
# 11  0435       B
# 12  0434       B
# 13  0415       B
# 14  0440       B
# 15  0696       C
# 16  0529       C
# 17  0175       A
# 18  0517       C
# 19  0648       C
# 20  0283       A
```

Answer (score 2):

Started with a comment but I'll move to a full answer.

Use Gregor's substring example to extract the portion you're interested in to a temporary variable. As he mentioned it could be a string or a factor (though definitely not numeric) so first convert it to string to be sure.

```
df$your_number_vector <- as.character(df$your_number_vector)
df$temp <- substr(your_number_vector, 1, 2)  # extract first two chars
```

Then use nested `ifelse()` statements with the OR bool operators to create your new variable.

```
df$var <- ifelse(df$temp == "01" || df$temp == "02", 
                 "A", 
                 ifelse(df$temp == "03" || df$temp == "04", 
                        "B", 
                        "C")  
                 )       
df$temp <- NULL  # drop the temp var
```

If you have more levels than this toy example (A:C) just keep nesting until you get to n-1 levels. However, if it goes much beyond this you'll probably want a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not as great as others but it is straightforward.

First I create a data.table:

```
sof <- data.table(value = c("011", "021", "031", "041", "051", "061"))

sof$temp <- substr(sof$value, 1, 2)
```

### #

Then create a list and a vector to loop through:

```
values <- list(c("01", "02"), c("03", "04"), c("05", "06"))

cats <- c("A", "B", "C")

for (i in seq(length(cats))) {  
   sof[.(values[[i]]), cat:= cats[i], on="temp"]
}
```